# How to change hours in duration to a number in google spreedsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to subtract a number form a duration but not sure how can I do it.
A1 : 137:47:00 (formatted as duration)
A2 : 126 (formatted as number)
When I subtract it is showing unexpected value
=(A1-A2) = -120.26

I was expecting something similar to 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtracting a number (without dimension) from a duration does not really make a lot of sense but if 137:47:00 represented 137 hours and 47 minutes then subtracting 126 hours from that would (and give a result between 11 and 12 hours). To be able to compare like with like, the duration can be represented as a number by accessing the fact that Google spreadsheets treats 24 hours as number 1. So multiply 137:47:00 (if representing hour, minutes, seconds) by `24` to get a number from which another number can be subtracted to give a meaningful result (ie 11.7833333 - representing 11 hours 47 minutes if to subtract 126 hours from 137 hours and 47 minutes). Therefore:

```
=24*A1-A2
```

might suit.

[Calculating time worked per day](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51972/calculating-time-worked-per-day) on Web Applications addresses a vaguely similar issue.